# play-services-ads:18.0.0 and appcompat-v7:28.0.0 - merger failed and dependencies using groupid com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library, androidx

I have an early version of play service and it was ok.
Now I update it to 18.0.0 and have many errors:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-35:15 to override.

my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {  details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` is underline in red saying that dependencies using groupid com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined.

any ideas how to solve this errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is happening because latest versions of `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` (in this case `v18.0.0`) is already using AndroidX but your app is still using Android Support.

So, there are two possibilities:

- Downgrade `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads`

If you downgrade the version of that library, this issue should be fixed because old versions were still using Support Library (and not AndroidX).

You can try for example:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0
```

[HERE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-ads?repo=google) you can find the list of released versions

- You should consider to migrate your app to AndroidX.

Support Library was deprecated. So, sooner or later, you will have to move to AndroidX. If do so, errors like this won't happen.